# measure texts code from programming pearls

Tags: c++

I have this code from programming pearls

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <string>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
void measure(char *text)
{
    cout<<"measure"<<text<<"\t";
    cout<<sizeof(t)<<"\n";
}
#define MEASURE(T,text){
cout<<text<<"\t";
 cout<<sizeof(T)<<"\t";
 int lastp=0;
  for (int i=0;i<11;i++){
      T *p=new T;
      int thisp=(int)p;
       if (lastp!=0)
            cout<<" "<<thisp-lastp;
       lastp=thisp;
  }
  cout<<"n":
  }

int main(){

     return 0;
}
```

but there are some mistakes

```
1>------ Build started: Project: new_practises, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  practises.cpp
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\new_practises\practises.cpp(11): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<<'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\new_practises\practises.cpp(11): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\new_practises\practises.cpp(12): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<<'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\new_practises\practises.cpp(12): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\new_practises\practises.cpp(12): error C2086: 'int cout' : redefinition
1>          c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\new_practises\practises.cpp(11) : see declaration of 'cout'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\new_practises\practises.cpp(14): error C2059: syntax error : 'for'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\new_practises\practises.cpp(14): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\new_practises\practises.cpp(14): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\new_practises\practises.cpp(14): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\new_practises\practises.cpp(14): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\new_practises\practises.cpp(14): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\new_practises\practises.cpp(14): error C2086: 'int i' : redefinition
1>          c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\new_practises\practises.cpp(14) : see declaration of 'i'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\new_practises\practises.cpp(14): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\new_practises\practises.cpp(14): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\new_practises\practises.cpp(14): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\new_practises\practises.cpp(21): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<<'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\new_practises\practises.cpp(21): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\new_practises\practises.cpp(21): error C2086: 'int cout' : redefinition
1>          c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\new_practises\practises.cpp(11) : see declaration of 'cout'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\new_practises\practises.cpp(22): error C2059: syntax error : '}'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\new_practises\practises.cpp(22): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\new_practises\practises.cpp(22): error C2059: syntax error : '}'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\new_practises\practises.cpp(24): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\new_practises\practises.cpp(24): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

What do I need to fix?

Comment: Which 'programming pearls' are you referring to?  I'm assuming it is not Jon Bentley's book "Programming Pearls" - it doesn't use C++, AFAICR (at least in the original edition) and does not include anything so coarse and un-pearl-like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Stephen's answer, I can say that #define is un-C++ish.  It becomes useful when you need a variable name that corresponds to a string or something the like.  For mostly all other cases, use functions.

Next to that, I must concur with DeadMG's opinion that at least I'm too stupid to see any reason to write this function.  But that's another concern :)

If you actually want to measure the length of a string, you can use the function [`strlen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strlen/).

What your `MEASURE` seems to do is print out a series of 11 newly allocated memory addresses.  Nice to do when you are studying the memory allocation strategy of your runtime, but otherwise not too useful.

Also don't forget to `delete` what you have `new`ed.

```
#define MEASURE(T,text) {\
    cout<<text<<"\t";\
    cout<<sizeof(T)<<"\t";\
    ...
```

can be directly translated into a template function: way easier to write, and to debug.

```
template< typename T > // assuming you _need_ a variable type of arguments
void MEASURE( const T& text) {
    cout<<text<<"\t";
    cout<<sizeof(T)<<"\t"; 
    // will write the size of e.g. one character.  Maybe
    // you should use strlen or the like...
    int lastp=0;
    for (int i=0;i<11;i++){
        T *p=new T;
        int thisp=(int)p;
        if (lastp!=0) cout<<" "<<thisp-lastp;
        lastp=thisp;
    }
    cout<<"n";
}
```

Comment: Should that not be const T& text, to keep the same usage as the #define?

Comment: Not really. If the argument is provided as a string literal or char[]: yes.  const char* arguments work differently.  Heck this code is worth a text book :)

Comment: If you had const T&, then T would just be deduced to be char*, but could also be std::string, etc. If, on the other hand, you had const T*, then you couldn't put in a std::string, whereas in the macro, you could.

Answer (score 1):

DeadMG is correct, there are quite a few mistakes here. The most prominent one is that you are not using `#define` correctly. It requires that all of the code of the function goes on one line.

```
#define func(A, B) {//function body goes here}
```

To allow multi-line `#define`s, use `\`s at the end of the lines:

```
#define MEASURE(T,text) {\
    cout<<text<<"\t";\
    cout<<sizeof(T)<<"\t";\
    int lastp=0;\
    for (int i=0;i<11;i++){\
        T *p=new T;\
        int thisp=(int)p;\
        if (lastp!=0) cout<<" "<<thisp-lastp;\
        lastp=thisp;\
    }\
    cout<<"n";\
}
```

(Note I have fixed a few typos here, including one `:` where a `;` should be.)

The other big problem with your code is in the measure function:

```
void measure(char *text)
{
    cout<<"measure"<<text<<"\t";
    cout<<sizeof(t)<<"\n";
}
```

What is `t`? I assume you mean `text`, not `t`.

The following should compile okay.

```
#include <iostream>

#define MEASURE(T,text) {\
    cout<<text<<"\t";\
    cout<<sizeof(T)<<"\t";\
    int lastp=0;\
    for (int i=0;i<11;i++){\
        T *p=new T;\
        int thisp=(int)p;\
        if (lastp!=0) cout<<" "<<thisp-lastp;\
        lastp=thisp;\
    }\
    cout<<"n";\
}

using namespace std;

template <class T>
void measure(char *text)
{
    cout<<"measure"<<text<<"\t";
    cout<<sizeof(text)<<"\n";
}

int main() {
     return 0;
}
```

As a final, not directly bug-related question to you - why are you using a `#define` like this? Why not simply write the `#define` code into the measure method? `#define`is usually used to give a short name for a variable or to declare very small functions - and there is a vocal part of the community that thinks they shouldn't be used at all!

Comment: He almost certainly meant T as the template parameter, not text. sizeof(char*) makes no sense. The function is still meaningless however. The main reason that I didn't fix all the bugs is because even if you fixed all the bugs, and created some input for the functions, you'd STILL get garbage and memory leaks back out.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of that. I must admit, my disclaimer for this code fix is that I barely read the actual code, and I'm not looking to fix the code logic (which I trust from the other comments/answers is badly broken). He asked how to fix the compilation errors, so that's what I helped with - I'll leave the discussions of what the code is meant to do to others!

Comment: Fair enough. It's not like this code's meaning is begging to be seen.

Comment: You should not use a pastebin when posting your answer to StackOverflow. Post the corrected code as part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

"some" mistakes? Whoever wrote that has NFI what on earth they're doing. The program doesn't even produce any meaningful output. ... or any output at all. You could literally not run it or read the source code and gain the same knowledge: zero.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "\" at the end of the line when your definition across multiple lines.
Below code is compiled  with no errors.

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
template <class T>
void measure(char *text)
{
    cout<<"measure"<<text<<"\t";
    cout<<sizeof(t)<<"\n";
}

#define MEASURE(T,text) { \
cout<<text<<"\t"; \
 cout<<sizeof(T)<<"\t"; \
 int lastp=0; \
  for (int i=0;i<11;i++){ \
      T *p=new T; \
      int thisp=(int)p; \
       if (lastp!=0) \
            cout<<" "<<thisp-lastp; \
       lastp=thisp; \
  } \
  cout<<"n": \
  }

int main(){

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: no i have changed but it has mistakes  and even what is   "stdafx.h"
there is no such kind of directory

Comment: stdafx is a Microsoft standard header for speeding up precompilation (if I remember correctly). If you aren't using a Microsoft product to code your C++ you neither have nor need it. Just skip that line.