# Stange error with preprocessor macro

Tags: c++

i have changed code style and aslo i hope it will   help
http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/spacemod.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MEASURE(T,  text)
{        \
   int i;
cout<<text<<"\t";                       \

 cout<<sizeof(T)<<"\t";                     \
 int lastp=0;\
  for ( i=0;i<11;i++){                \
      T *p=new T;                                  \
      int thisp=(int)p;                                   \
       if (lastp!=0)   cout<<" "<<thisp-lastp;           \
       lastp=thisp;                             \
  }                                                                     \
  cout<<"n";\
  }                                                     \
  using namespace std;
template <class T>
void measure(char *text)
{
    cout<<"measure"<<text<<"\t";  
    cout<<sizeof(T)<<"\n";
}
int main(){



     return 0;
}
```

it has only one mistake

```
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\measure\measure.cpp(5): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

Comment: please see
http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/spacemod.cpp

Comment: possible duplicate of [measure texts  code from programming pearls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329142/measure-texts-code-from-programming-pearls)

Comment: @sbi: While that is normally true, in this case the accepted answer on the old question solves the issue expressed here as well, so I don't see any value in having this question open. In fact, it looks like davit-datuashvili just copy/pasted the code given to him in that answer and then changed the position of the backslashes for some strange reason, causing the errors.

Comment: @interjay: Yeah, he's kept spamming with meaningless questions with lots of awful code. I've now voted to close this one. Still, I'd suggest giving a better rational for voting to close such a question in the future. In general, posting a new question is what's been encouraged over modifying the original, after all.

Answer (score 9):

I'm pretty certain you need a `\` at the end of the `#define` line itself as well as the `int i;`, and possibly the empty lines in that macro as well (I'm not sure about that).

I suspect the `\` on the line preceding your `using` statement is dodgy as well.

However, the one thing I'm absolutely certain about is that you would be better off using inline functions than `#define` macros.

While `inline` doesn't *guarantee* that it's actually inlined, I tend to always leave optimisation up to the compiler.

And code macros, I frown on that pretty heavily in C++, especially for complex things like this :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a line continuation character on the first line of the macro. You can see what your macros expand into by running the preprocessor (e.g with G++ use the -E flag).

That said, I don't see why you should need a macro in the first place. Why not use a simple template function?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, its the continuation character after the #define as you got from the prevoius answears. You should try to avoid defines as far as possible, exactly because they can lead to such errors which don't mean anything. 
I think you did that define to increase performance, but there is a better way to do this. Define this function as an "inline" function in the header. You can read more about inline functions for example here: 
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions2/